# Dúvida com criação de For no Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift-3

Estou seguindo um curso de iOS e no curso mostra o `for` desta forma:

```
for var i = 1; i <= 10; i++ {

}
```

Mas tenho uma mensagem de erro, isso mudou? Como poderia ser feito isso da forma nova?

> error: CriandoLoop.playground:6:1: error: C-style for statement has been removed in Swift 3

Comment: Mudou sim. Esse é um `for` que veio do C. O IDE está a dizer que tens uma maneira melhor para o fazer e que deves seguir a linguagem com a sua sintaxe. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html

Answer (score 0):

Vai imprimir de 1 ate 10

```
for i in 1 ... 10 {
    print(i)
}
```

Vai imprimir de 1 ate 9

```
for i in 1 ..< 10 {
    print(i)
}
```